# How to calculate Zero Crossing Rate with PyAudio stream data

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I am trying to make to make some speech detection code. I am trying to do this with zero crossing rate. I did some research and found that when someone is speaking, the zero crossing rate should be a medium kinda value, not too high and not too low, but when I speak into the microphone the zero crossing rate becomes higher than it was with just background noise(which there is barely any) this is what I am doing to calculate it right now.

```
((audioData[:-1] * audioData[1:]) < 0).sum()
```

audioData is a numpy table and it's content is the result of pyAudioStream.read() could anyone tell me the correct way to calculate this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of unnecessary multiplication.  Using a Boolean comparison and running it through `np.diff` will probably be faster:

```
zero_crosses = np.nonzero(np.diff(audioData > 0)))[0]
```

What this is doing:

1. creates a boolean array of where the signal is above 0 (`audioData > 0`)
2. does a pairwise difference (`np.diff`) so locations of zero crossings become 1 (rising) and -1 (falling)
3. picks the index of the array where those nonzero values are (`np.nonzero`).

Then if you want the number of crossings, you can just take `zero_crosses.size`.

As a bonus you have the timings of all the crosses so you can do things like a histogram that shows where more crosses are happening in your time history.